# Components doesn't render a function called from render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been trying to figure out why renderFilteredList does not render these list items (both of them include the substring this.props.searchedWord and the console logs true, and renderFilteredList is called from the original render function).

```
{<li key={singleObject.body} className="list-group-item">{singleObject.body}</li>} 
{<li key={singleObject.name} className="list-group-item">{singleObject.name}</li>}
```

and I couldn't figure out why, can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code please?

```
renderFilteredList(){
    console.log('the data to fetch is: ', this.props.dataFetched, 'and the searchedWord is: ', this.props.searchedWord);
    return this.props.dataFetched.map(objects=>{
            return objects.map(singleObject=>{
                console.log(singleObject.body.includes(this.props.searchedWord), singleObject.name.includes(this.props.searchedWord));
            <div>
                {<li key={singleObject.body} className="list-group-item">{singleObject.body}</li>}
                {<li key={singleObject.name} className="list-group-item">{singleObject.name}</li>}
                <hr/>
            </div>
             })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the `<div>` within the map function.  Right now you are returning nothing.

I'm also just assuming that you are calling this method within the return of your render method.  If you are simply calling it but returning nothing from render, you'll still not get anything to the display.

```
renderFilteredList(){
  console.log('the data to fetch is: ', this.props.dataFetched, 'and the searchedWord is: ', this.props.searchedWord);
  return this.props.dataFetched.map(objects => {
    return objects.map(singleObject => {
      console.log(singleObject.body.includes(this.props.searchedWord), singleObject.name.includes(this.props.searchedWord));
      return (
        <div>
          {<li key={singleObject.body} className="list-group-item">{singleObject.body}</li>}
          {<li key={singleObject.name} className="list-group-item">{singleObject.name}</li>}
          <hr/>
        </div>
      );
    });
  });
}
```